# Issue in fetching JSON data from MYSQL and parsing it to array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wanted to store array into my MYSQL columns hence I upgraded my MYSQL version to 5.7. I have created a table with column as JSON type.

My Need is, I will have to store an array in this column.

Hence what I did was,
First.

I want $my_array to be stored in database as json format,

```
$my_array = ["a","b","c"];
```

I'm storing it in the Database column lets say `alphabets` by converting it to JSON using `json_encode($my_array)`.

```
$words_samples = "hello man!";
$my_array = ["a","b","c"];
$my_array = json_encode($my_array);
```

I'm using Codeigniter, So I'll write the SQL query that i'm using.

```
INSERT INTO english ('alphabets', 'words_samples') 
VALUES ($my_array, $words_samples);
```

Insert is successful with database column output as `["a","b","c"]`

Now, I need the `alphabets` and `words_sample` data retrieved and displayed in a json.

Code :

```
SELECT * from english;
```

In my PHP,

```
echo json_decode($data).
```

Now the `alphabets` data is displayed as `[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]` rather than `["a","b","c"]`

I see since the `alphabets` column is already in JSON encoding it to JSON again is giving some other Output.
How do I prevent double parsing of the `alphabets` data alone?

Comment: `json_decode` should return an array in this case, so you shouldn't be able to `echo` it like that. Anyway, please share a code sample.

Comment: Prior to `json_decode` what is `$data`? What is the data stored in the DB as?

Comment: Seems that your data is already in json in the database.  I fail to understand why you call json_decode on the json-encoded string if you want to return a json-encoded string.  I do also need to see your code, because json decoding `["a","b","c"]` should result in a php array.  Please provide a minimal verifiable example of what you're seeing and we can help.

Comment: I have many other data from that table being fetched and one of it is in JSON datatype. Hence I'll have to encode it to json along with other columns. I suppose there is double encode being happening to the `alphabets`.  How do I prevent it?

Comment: OP Updated with source codes. (I can't add the original codes as they are heavy and hard to understand. Hence I have simplified it as short as possible)

Comment: What is the value of `$data` right after retrieving it from the database? Also what does it look like within the DB itself?

Comment: Could you use var_dump instead of echoing and show us the results? `var_dump(json_decode($data))`

Comment: Storing arrays in SQL is a bad idea. The JSON datatype is an improvement, but it's still painful. I strongly suggest that you normalize the data instead of storing a JSON array.

Comment: It sounds like the array is being encoded twice, maybe CodeIgniter is doing its own encoding.

Comment: How are you actually running the query? `VALUES ($my_array, $words_samples)` would throw a syntax error.